# How to make *.vue file in nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I know that my question seems weird but I'm seriously lost in here, I read some article to redirect all not-found page in nuxt to `/` or `home` or `index` but in this tutorial tell me to make `page/*.vue`. First of all I know that `*` this `asterisk` symbol means `all` but whenever I try to make `*.vue` file it always give me not valid files in `Visual Studio Code`. can someone help me to solve this?

this is the article that I read [redirect-404-not-found-in-nuxt-js](https://vuedose.tips/tips/redirect-404-not-found-in-nuxt-js/) I already try the code in this article and it works and redirect my `404.vue` page to home but it is not the solution I seek since it means I must declare all possible file for not found and of course it is not a good solution.

this is the `404.vue` code that I want to use in `*.vue`:

```
<!-- pages/*.vue -->
<script>
export default {
  asyncData ({ redirect }) {
    return redirect('/')
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try this.
https://nuxtjsorg/guide/async-data#handling-errors or https://nuxtjsorg/guide/routing#validate-route-params

Comment: Where in Nuxt.js documentation did you read `*` for a page name mean `all`? In Nuxt, parameterized routes begin with `_` and reusable page code across pages should be put in `/layouts` vue files.

Comment: @SteveHynding Yeah when I read it again I think that my mistake, My friend Point it to me that I must use `_.vue` but I put it in `pages/`, but it still not work when deployed?

Answer (score 1):

*.vue is not a valid file name. I didn't use Nuxt when creating my 404 page - I just used regular old Vue.

First I created a component and called mine notFoundComponent.vue (can call yours whatever) and created a View as well and called that notFoundView.vue. I then coded those pages to display the 404 error how I wanted.

On my router.js page, I added the following to the end of the routes and it works as intended:

```
{ name: 'notFoundView', path: '*', component: notFoundView }
```